# Can I read input data from files spread across Dask worker nodes?

Tags: file, cluster-computing, dask, distributed

Trying to read a large amount of data into Dask cluster of 4 computers.  Is it possible to distribute the data files across all 4 machines so that reading the data into Dask isn't bottlenecked by data files sitting on one machine?

If this is possible, how do I specify it?

Comment: where is the data currently? where are the computers?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado the servers are in a data center.  Does it matter where the servers are located?

Comment: I mean how do you access the data and servers? is it aws s3? google cloud storage? a custom NAT you access over SFTP? or are all the files currently sitting on the disk drive of one of the four machines? yes, your approach will differ based on the answers.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado , per the question, the files are on the servers.  Local storage.

Comment: got it. then no - use normal server operations like mounting/unmounting disks, using cloud storage, etc to copy the data, then open it with dask.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado, asking about Dask.  I have parquet files on one machine where I also run the Python code to read the files into dask dataframe.  Running on one machine, read is fine, but slow.  Thus, the calculation is slow.  I added another machine to the cluster so now there are two machines.  Twice as many workers so should be faster, right?  Not at all.  Much slower and this.  
```distributed.core - INFO - Event loop was unresponsive in Worker for 6.55s.  This is often caused by long-running GIL-holding functions or moving large chunks of data. This can cause timeouts and instability.```

Comment: yep - your data and cluster setup matters. I use dask regularly on a Google Kubernetes cluster set up with [daskhub](https://blog.dask.org/2020/08/31/helm_daskhub). the data is stored on google cloud storage, which is accessible by all of the workers. many other people use dask on HPCs with networked storage. dask is not designed to magically solve storage access issues - if your workers don't have any way to access the storage then you're going to be limited by read speeds if your job is read-intensive. no way around that. this isn't a dask issue but a workflow one. good luck!

Comment: if you're on one of the cloud providers, I would strongly recommend writing the data to a cloud storage location (such as s3, azure blob storage, google cloud storage, etc) rather than to the machine's disk if you want to make it available to the workers with dask.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado You assumed I was doing this in the cloud.  I'm not.  Local on-prem machines, and again, local storage.  Files are on one machine.  Is there a configuration so that each worker gets part of the data?  Surely this question has come up before, no?

Comment: to be fair, you asked a networking question without providing details :) I'm just trying to be helpful. you cannot do this. No, there is no configuration within dask that just makes the data on your computer available to other computers. if you have a network administrator you might ask for their help, to see if there is a way to provide networked access to data. but dask can't (and shouldn't) open a backdoor in your computer so that other computers can access the hard disk.